# How to make images in grid to grow vertically when changing browser width?

Tags: html, css

Here is the example I am trying to achieve [image: grid example]

I want left and right image to always be the same height, and height of the block in the middle should be equal to the height of the left image.
Even more I need images to grow vertically when I change browser width.

I am stuck and not sure how to achieve such result. Instead of images I could utilize `div` elements with the background.

Specifically I am not sure how to make image heights of the inner block to grow in height with the browser width, and I do not want to use JavaScript to achieve such result

In my current efforts I can make all the columns to be the same height, however, when I change browser width there is more space added between columns.

[image]

Comment: why dont you use @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) css property

Comment: @rishit_s this will not work and in fact I only target tablets, desktops and extra wide desktops up to certain point. I need to avoid spacing between columns by making images bigger on bigger screens

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to achieve meaningful result with the div blocks and background images

[image]

```
const drDefaultStyles = {
  container: {

  },

  header: {
    borderBottom: 'solid 1px #dddddd',
    color: '#898989',
    textAlign:'left',
    marginBottom: '20px',
  },

  header_title: {
    fontSize: '14px',
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    fontFamily: 'Platino',
    textTransform: 'capitalize',
    margin: 0,
    fontWeight: 100,
  },

  tall: {
    height: '250px',
  },

  half_tall: {
    height: '120px',
  },

  image_container: {
    position: 'relative',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    background: 'rgb(245, 245, 245)',
    padding: '10px',
  },

  image: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundPosition: 'center center',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
  },

  title: {
    position: 'absolute',
    display: 'inline-block',
    bottom: '25px',
    background: 'rgba(245, 245, 245, .85)',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    padding: '7px 15px',
  },
}


<section className="container" style={ _s.container }>
      <div className="row" style={ _s.header }>
        <h2 style={ _s.header_title }>Destination races</h2>
      </div>

      <div className="row" style={ _s.container }>
        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style={{ ..._s.tall, paddingLeft: 0, paddingRight: '5px' }}>
          <div style={ _s.image_container }>
            <div style={{ ..._s.image, backgroundImage: 'url(/images/cities/leadville.jpg)' }}></div>
            <span style={ _s.title }>Leadville</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style={{ padding: 0 }}>
          <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style={{ ..._s.half_tall, marginBottom: '10px', padding: 0 }}>
            <div style={ _s.image_container }>
              <div style={{ ..._s.image, backgroundImage: 'url(/images/cities/san-francisco.jpg)' }}></div>
              <span style={ _s.title }>San Francisco</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" style={{ ..._s.half_tall, float: 'left', padding: 0, paddingRight: '5px' }}>
            <div style={ _s.image_container }>
              <div style={{ ..._s.image, backgroundImage: 'url(/images/cities/miami.jpg)' }}></div>
              <span style={ _s.title }>Miami</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-md-7 col-xs-7"  style={{ ..._s.half_tall, float: 'left', padding: 0 }}>
            <div style={ _s.image_container }>
              <div style={{ ..._s.image, backgroundImage: 'url(/images/cities/chicago.jpg)' }}></div>
              <span style={ _s.title }>Chicago</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style={{ ..._s.tall, paddingLeft: '5px', paddingRight: 0 }}>
          <div style={ _s.image_container }>
            <div style={{ ..._s.image, backgroundImage: 'url(/images/cities/new-york.jpg)' }}></div>
            <span style={ _s.title }>New York City</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</section>
```